# node js - web page sometimes raise 404 error

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404

my web site sometimes raise 404 error even though there is correct path in my index file.
When occurs 404 error, I reload the page and the page correctly uploaded.
even though by reloading the page successfully page uploaded, I think it's not stable...
Do you have any idea? I don't know why it happens.

This is my route and handler to main page!
And I used vhost to connect domain

```
app1.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  var arr = poplist;
  var type = 'recommended';
  var session = null;
  if(req.session.user){
    session = req.session;
  }
  if (req.session.series_id){ /*5*/
    var search_car = req.session.series_id;
    arr.unshift({'id':req.session.series_id,'series_name':req.session.manu_name + ' ' + req.session.series_name});
    type = 'mycar';
  } else {
    var search_car = recommend_car(arr).id; /*4*/
  }
  get_recommend_container(arr,function(err,recommend_container){
    if (err) { res.send('err') }
    else {
      get_best_reviews_container(function(err,best_reviews_container){
        if (err) { res.send('err') }
        else {
          /*search_car for query in menubar*/
          res.render('main', {'type':type,'poplist':poplist,'recommend_container':recommend_container,'best_reviews_container':best_reviews_container,'search_car':search_car,'session':session});
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

....

```
app.use(vhost('mysite.com', app1));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send('Sorry cannot find the page!');
});

app.listen(8000,'myip',function(){
  console.log("Connected to 8000 port!..")
});
```

Comment: post a code snippet of your node routes and controller

Comment: @Ridham Tarpara what part should I have to load in my code? I am worried because my index file has lots lots of lines

Comment: path where you define your route and handler which you called to handle route

Comment: It's not a good sign if your index file is so big you have no idea what part could fail.

Comment: @JeremyThille Oh my.. Is it possible that index file fails because of other routes(ex: mysite.com/apage) even when I enter into main page(ex:mysite.com)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You explicitely define a "404 middleware" :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send('Sorry cannot find the page!');
});
```

This means that every time your app will receive any request, it will execute that middleware that will send back a 404.

Documentation : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

> This example shows a middleware function with no mount path. The
>   function is executed every time the app receives a request.

```
var app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time:', Date.now())
  next()
})
```

Comment: thank you! I will try! But the 404 page doesn't show 'Sorry cannot find the page!' but 404 nginx error page. Is it a same problem?

Comment: Ah, you never spoke about Nginx, so that's a totally different problem. All your question is probably irrelevant in that case, because it's not a Node issue but an Nginx configuration issue. And I suck at Nginx, that's a Devops problem...

Comment: what..? Is node not familiar with Nginx..? I didn't know about that... Then It can be the issue between Nginx and node js not my index file...

Comment: But I want to try anything to make site stable. Will seperating the index file be helpful to make the site stable?

Comment: `Is node not familiar with Nginx`, that doesn't make much sense. Nginx is a reverse proxy, Node is your server, it could be anything else (a Java server, etc). They are two different things. For instance, I use Nginx to redirect the port 80 to the port 5000 where my Node app actually runs. But that's on a production server, and apparently you're still in development... Why is Nginx even here?

Comment: Sorry about my explanation. Because I have less knowledge about server, I might misunderstand and not completely explain what is wrong with my server. I understood that you said setting node server on Nginx default conf is not a good choice.